# How to make maxima display results as products of square roots?

Tags: maxima

When trying to add two products of square roots for example, 5*sqrt(2)+5*sqrt(2), instead of getting 10sqrt(2), Maxima will output 2*5^(3/2). While it is correct, is there a way to make it display as 10*sqrt(2)?